# Conexão SQL com Dapper/Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper

Estou começando no Asp.net Core e estou com dificuldades para conectar meu banco SQl. Segue abaixo o meu Model
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha classe de conexao
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

appsetting.json
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

startup.cs
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Controller
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro apresentado ao tentar executar
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fiz referencia no Nuget com o Dapper. Por favor me ajudem a entender onde estou errando na conexao com o SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Se você olhar o código fonte do asp.net core em https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Configuration/Config.Abstractions/src/ConfigurationExtensions.cs

Pode perceber que a extensão **GetConnectionString** funciona como atalho para a seção "`ConnectionStrings`", então altere o seu appsettings.json para:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "ConnectionLoja": ....
}
```

Dica: É interessante publicar as questões com o código fonte e não uma imagem, facilita as respostas.

Answer (score 0):

A dica do Rafael já diz bastante o que deve fazer se for utilizar métodos `GetConnectionStrings`, mas se você precisa por algum motivo muito especifico utilizar a ConnectionString a partir da configuração ilustrada `{ Data : { ConnectionLoja: ...}`, basta utilizar `var dataLoja = configuration.GetSection("DataLoja").Get<DataLoja>();`